# Reconnect WinSCP after a connection failed while keeping remote directory up to date

Tags: ftp, synchronization, winscp

I want to keep a local directory synced remotely through FTP. If my internet connection is ready, I can easily use WinSCP.com to connect to the FTP and keep files up-to-date using the command:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /script=connect.script
```

Where my script is:

```
# Connect
open myftp
# Change remote directory
cd /

# Set options
option batch continue
option reconnecttime 120
option confirm off

# Synchronize
synchronize remote
# Keep Up-to-date
keepuptodate -delete
```

The FTP server is a Filezilla Server version 0.9.54 correctly set up. The 'myftp' parameter is a section configured and named using the WinSCP GUI.

Problem is: when I lose connection (like someone remove the cable from the server machine) the WinSCP service dies.

```
Connected
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] myftp
/
batch           continue
reconnecttime   120
reconnecttime   120
confirm         off
Comparing...
Nothing to Synchronize.
Watching for changes, press Ctrl-C to abort...
Scanning '.' for subdirectories...
Watching for changes in 2 directories...
Lost connection.
Disconnected from server
Server is going offline
Session 'myftp' closed.
No session.
winscp>
```

I was expecting that the 'keepuptodate' would keep the section alive and retry during 120 seconds, based on parameter 'reconnecttime'. Why is it not happening?

I found a "trick" by using a Windows batch file and 'goto' command that keeps calling WinSCP if the session closes, but it is clumsy and I wonder if there is a better solution.

I'm using WinSCP version 5.7.6 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no better solution.

Your solution with the `goto` loop is the easiest solution, you can get, to get reconnected for the `keepuptodate` command.

See the official [WinSCP example for retrying script/connection attempt](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_retry).

Of course, your WinSCP script needs to end with the [`exit` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_exit), so that it automatically closes.

Comment: Thank you. It is not ideal, but I'll keep this approach. It really bothers me that WinSCP can't deal with it by itself.